# For Looping through ADuser List

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a script to go through the ADUser database and select certain people/data. Here's my current code:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties extensionattribute9,Displayname,mail 

$results = $users | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.extensionattribute9 -like '*Smith*')
    {
      select Displayname,mail
    }
}
$results
```

Once this works, I'll be adding a few more foreach-object loops, getting more users that have certain other extensionattribute9 values. But for just this first one it runs with no errors, but doesn't display anything once it finishes. Am I doing something wrong with the extensionattribute9 variable? I tried the script without the $_., and it predictably said it couldn't recognize the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
select Displayname,mail
```

to

```
$_ | select Displayname,mail
```

Comment: Thank you! That totally worked. Could you explain why I needed to add that $_ ?

Comment: Because you want to select some properties of your pipeline variable $_. Without piping $_ to select there is nothing to select from - hope that makes sense. If not I will try to explain it in more detail tonight

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Since he's using a pipeline anyway it would be best to replace the `ForEach-Object` including the nested `if` statement with a `Where-Object` filter: `$users | Where-Object { $_.extensionattribute9 -like '*Smith*' } | select Displayname,mail`