# loops in Powershell

Tags: powershell, system-administration

I'm not so sure how to do loops in Powershell.

```
get-aduser -Filter {name -like "USER"} >C:\temp.txt
```

I have a list of 200 users (I have first and last name) specific that I would like the logon name to same file how can I do that with the command a I wrote before? Or is there any other way to did it ?

Comment: You have a file of first and last name? Can you add some example line?

Comment: But to answer your question, Powershell has a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7) statement. And there is also [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/423284-powershell-script-to-read-user-names-from-a-txt-file-and-export-ad-data-into-csv).

Comment: Usually -like uses wildcards `*`.

Comment: What is the format of your list?  Is it a CSV with column names or just like:  john doe \r\n jane doe, etc?

Comment: Hi I'm have a file csv with first name and last name. I can convert it to txt file if need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For Looping through ADuser List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813139/for-looping-through-aduser-list)... this should show you how to loop through the accounts

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop like @msanford said and loop through your user list with something like this:

```
get-aduser -Filter {Name -like "USER*"} | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp.txt
```

Comment: yes, but I need to take a file with 200 people.
I'm not sure how I take SCV with column names.

Comment: maybe something like this?                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                            $csv_data = Import-Csv -Path C:\Scripts\test2.scv -Delimiter "," | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName | Out-File -FilePath C:\Scripts\test3.scv